How to install Laravel 9 with Docker. This is the command: curl -s https://laravel.build/example | sh, but when I do it it installs version 11 for me
I want to install Laravel 9 with sail, but when I execute: curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | sh , the command installs Laravel 11.
Is there a command that allows me to specify which version I want to install?
A command equivalent to this:
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app
I tried this: curl -s "https://laravel.build/devjobs" | sh  , but this command installs Laravel 11, I want to install Laravel 9.

Have you tried DDEV? It is a wrapper for Docker that makes things extremely easy.
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#laravel
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Ohh, thank you very much, I'm going to try DDEV

When you access the URL https://laravel.build/example-app, you can view the bash script to install laravel. The command laravel new example-app will install the latest laravel since that is what laravel new does. Check this docs for reference
What you can do is either create your own bash script and change laravel new example-app to composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app OR manually run commands create-project, install sail etc.
For reference you can do the following:
Assuming that you are in linux with docker installed, create a laravel9.sh file with the following contents
docker info > /dev/null 2>&1

# Ensure that Docker is running...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker is not running."

    exit 1
fi

docker run --rm \
    --pull=always \
    -v "$(pwd)":/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    bash -c "create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app --no-interaction && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailpit,selenium "

cd example-app

# Allow build with no additional services..
if [ "mysql redis meilisearch mailpit selenium" == "none" ]; then
    ./vendor/bin/sail build
else
    ./vendor/bin/sail pull mysql redis meilisearch mailpit selenium
    ./vendor/bin/sail build
fi

CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHT_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
BOLD='\033[1m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo ""

if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo -e "${BOLD}Get started with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
else
    echo -e "${BOLD}Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.${NC}"
    echo ""
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo ""
    echo -e "${BOLD}Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
fi

Make your laravel9.sh file executable
chmod +x laravel9.sh
Execute laravel.sh
./laravel9.sh
This script will do the following:

Download PHP 8.2 from Laravel sail's docker profile
Install Laravel 9
Run other services.

If you are in windows, do what windows do to create executable files (.bat)

Or you can do the manual commands (without executable, can be done in windows too):

Execute docker run on sail:

docker run --rm \
    --pull=always \
    -v "$(pwd)":/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    bash -c "create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app --no-interaction && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailpit,selenium "


Pull other services

cd example-app
./vendor/bin/sail pull mysql redis meilisearch mailpit selenium
./vendor/bin/sail build

2.b If you are in linux, change ownership is needed
sudo chown -R $USER: .


Build your assets

./vendor/bin/sail up


1) composer create-project (depends on having php and composer installed)
You can use the --ignore-platform-reqs option to prevent composer from nagging you about dependencies you might be missing (since you're going to develop on sail, your host machine shouldn't need anything aside from docker)
Create project
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 devjobs --ignore-platform-reqs

Require sail
cd devjobs

composer require laravel/sail --dev --ignore-platform-requs

Install sail
php artisan sail:install

./vendor/bin/sail up -d

If you don't have composer installed, first get Composer
2) git clone and docker run
Clone the laravel/laravel repo
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git devjobs

Remove repo files
cd devjobs

rm -rf .git/
rm -rf .github/
rm .styleci.yml

Install composer dependencies through docker
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

Install dependencies (including sail) through docker
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    composer require laravel/sail --ignore-platform-reqs

Publish sail's docker-compose file
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php82-composer:latest \
    php artisan sail:install --no-interaction

./vendor/bin/sail up -d


Thank you so much, I tried this and it worked correctly

Never use older versions of Laravel.
Laravel9 is already EOL.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases
Always use the latest version when creating a new project.
